# sorting datagrid in silverlight using Observable Collection

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I have an observable collection which is binded to datagrid... I want to sort the datagrid by clicking on header. It's a dynamic data. Here is my code

```
namespace SLSortObservableCollection
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        //ObservableCollection<int> NumData = new ObservableCollection<int>();
       // ObservableCollection<string> StrData = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       ObservableCollection<int> NumData = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    ObservableCollection<string> StrData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random ra = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int num = ra.Next(1000);
            NumData.Add(num);

        }
        try
        {

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = NumData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Random random = new Random();
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
                StrData.Add(builder.ToString());
            }

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = StrData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }

}  

}
```

Comment: Can anyone please  help ...I want to sort the column by clicking on the header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObservableCollection does not support sorting at all. If this was not silverlight, you might be able to do something with CollectionView.

As it is, you will probably have to use a custom extension of SortableCollection. There are several of these flying around, just search for "sortable observableCollection"

Some implementations to get you started

http://kiwigis.blogspot.de/2010/03/how-to-sort-obversablecollection.html

http://elegantcode.com/2009/05/14/write-a-sortable-observablecollection-for-wpf/

http://sortablecollection.codeplex.com/

Comment: can we use something like columnheader_Click Event and then call sorting function in that event.....

Comment: Also the important part here is that I have to sort the column by clicking on the column header...and Silverlight5 datagrid does not have "ColumnHeaderClik" event

Comment: If the custom ObservableCollection implements IComparable, it should just work, like it does with a normal List. No need to add any click events. (have not tested this myself)